# Can an external / guest / B2B collaboration user access Dynamics Operations OData?

Tags: oauth, odata, azure-active-directory, microsoft-dynamics, adal

Does the Microsoft Dynamics Finance & Operations OData service support users from a different Azure AD tenant?

My O365 account can access the Dynamics Finance & Operations instance of another organization/tenant. I believe that means my account is a "B2B Collaboration User"(?)

An Azure Active Directory native application has been set up in the external tenant's Azure portal, with relevant Microsoft ERP API permissions:

- Access AX as organization users
- Access AX data
- Access AX custom service

The application id / client id has been registered in Finance & Operations (Admin > Setup > AAD apps).

I can use OAuth Authorization Code Grant flow to get a bearer access token.

But when I try to access the OData service (e.g. .../data/Customers) using the access token, I only get a "401 Unauthorized" response with no content.

Is this scenario not supported, or has a step been missed?

Answer (score 0):

401 Unauthorized may due to access token is missing, invalid, or is revoked. Please request a new token from the authorization server.

And you could also parse the access_token by [jwt.io](https://jwt.io) to check it.